# What's the easiest method of changing the drive letter of the active/boot drive in Win 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, boot, drive-letter

I recently bought an SSD to accompany my HDD, and installed a fresh copy of Windows 7 onto it. I then used Drive Manager to change the drive letter of my HDD from C: to E:.

Trouble is, I now have windows installed on my SSD, which is drive letter D:. In order to boot up my computer, I have to go through Windows Boot Manager every time to choose the correct windows installation. I tried changing the boot priority from my HDD to my SSD in my bios, but it didn't boot properly probably because I don't have a C: drive. So that's what I'm trying to do now.

I currently have a win 7 install disc on hand, and I know that I could easily just reinstall windows and change the drive letter in the process, but i've already done it twice for other reasons and I don't want to worry about losing any more files that i've forgotten about and reinstalling programs that don't come with ninite. Is there an easier way of changing my drive letter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, from the current Windows location (the Windows installation that really works), go to start -> type msconfig.exe -> press Enter. Click Yes if UAC prompts. Go to Boot tab. You can find a list of Windows boot entry, the same as you see during boot. Select the one that works and click on *Select as default*. Then click on Apply and then Ok. Restart the PC to check.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my boot issue. I still don't have a C: drive, but at this point I don't think I need one.